# Expected value of multiplication of elements in a normal vector

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

Suppose we distributed vector $X=[x_1,...,x_N]$ from $N(0,\Sigma)$, in which $\Sigma \in R^{N\times N}$

Now how can I compute $E[x_ix_j]$?

How can I compute $E[x_i^2 x_j  x_s]?$

($i,j,s\in [1,N]$)

Comment: If this is connected to an homework, exercise or assessment, please add the `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 1):

When considering a normal vector$$X\sim\mathfrak{N}_4(0,\Sigma)$$the conditional distribution of a component $X_1$ conditional on the remaining components $X^1$ is a normal distribution
$$\mathfrak{N}_1(\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}X^1,\Sigma_{11}-\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21})$$when decomposing
$$\Sigma=\left[\begin{matrix}\Sigma_{11} &\Sigma_{12}\\\Sigma_{21} &\Sigma_{22}\\\end{matrix}\right]$$
Using the telescoping formula $$\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2X_3X_4]=\mathbb{E}_{X_4}[\mathbb{E}_{X_3}(\mathbb{E}_{X_2}\{\mathbb{E}_{X_1}[X_1X_2X_3X_4|X_2,X_3,X_4]|X_3,X_4\}|X_4)]$$ and the successive three conditional Gaussian distributions should see you through.

Comment: in my question the length of the vector $X$ is more than the number of variables which we aim to compute expectation. I mean $v>4$. does your solution work for this problem? I am not sure

Comment: You may have 10⁶ components, but if you are only interested in a product of four components the other ones do not matter.